# FluentValidation, validate a property based on another properties value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation, fluentvalidation

This is my model:

```
public class StaffMemberTask
{
    public int StaffMemberTaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public Initiator InitiateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartFromDate { get; set; }
}

public enum Initiator
{
    StartDate,
    DateOfBirth,
    SpecificDate,
    Birthday
}
```

I want to validate that `StartFromDate` is not null (or maybe `DateTime.Min`) if `InitiateFrom == Initiator.SpecificDate`.

I have tried these combinations but I just cannot get the validation to trigger on `StartFromDate`:

```
RuleFor(x => x.StartFromDate).NotNull().DependentRules(() =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.InitiateFrom).Equals(Initiator.SpecificDate);
});

RuleFor(x => x.StartFromDate).NotNull().When(x => x.InitiateFrom == Initiator.SpecificDate);

RuleFor(p => p.StartFromDate).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().When(x => x.InitiateFrom == Initiator.SpecificDate);
```

Does the fact I'm evaluating against an enum in anyway affect what I'm doing because I cannot understand why one of the above validation rules wouldn't have worked.

Comment: All three rules work for me. Please ensure that the problem you are facing is reproducible by your code example.

Comment: I just don't understand it @Prolog. If I reduce the validator to `RuleFor(x => x.StartFromDate).NotNull();` the validation works (not as intended obviously). As soo as I add `.When(x => x.InitiateFrom == Initiator.SpecificDate);` to it, it fails.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that if I let it do a roundtrip to the server, the validation fails as expected, the record doesn't save and the validation error is shown. It's just not triggering client side.

Comment: Your question don't mention client side. _"Note that not all rules defined in FluentValidation will work with ASP.NET’s client-side validation. For example, any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side."_ ~[FluentValidation docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation) The validation you showed works on server-side. If you are aiming for similar client-side validation, I'm afraid you'll have to do some JS scripting. There is no out of the box solution for this.

Comment: Facepalm. Thank you for your efforts.